# Chrome 32.0.1700.76 Heading Font Weight Issues

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I've notived that some font weights are not working in chrome 32.0.1700.76. IVe updated it today, and font weights smaller (lighter) than 300 are displayed as 400 for some reason, for any heading class (h1, h2, h3, h4, h6, h6).

You can test it with Lato here. I've tested it on multiple windows 7 machines, same result.
http://typecast.com/preview/google/Lato

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed the same thing since updating to version 32. For me, it is happening on a p tag as well as heading tags.

I have submitted a bug report to Google.

Comment: I also noticed it's not only happening to light, but sometimes the extrabold/black as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a workaround, add !important to the definition:

```
h2 { font-weight:300 !important; }
```